# How to solve this iconv exception?

Tags: ruby

The following code:

```
def convertToUTF8 str
  str = Iconv.conv('ASCII//IGNORE', 'UTF8', str).gsub("\x00", "") # line 585
  str.chomp!
  str
end
```

Raises exception:

```
myfile.rb:585: in `conv': invalid encoding ("ASCII", "UTF8") (Iconv::InvalidEncoding)
```

This error is on my macbook pro. But same code can run one my peer's macbook pro. So I suppose it should be a environment problem.

I tried to use following code:

```
 # The following two lines are in bar.rb
 require 'iconv'
 puts Iconv.list
```

Then execute bar.rb:

```
 $ ruby bar.rb | grep UTF # ruby version is 1.9.1-p376
 UTF-8 
 UTF-8-MAC
 UTF8-MAC
 UTF-16
 UTF-16BE
 UTF-16LE
 UTF-32
 UTF-32BE
 UTF-32LE
 UNICODE-1-1-UTF-7
 UTF-7
 CSUNICODE11UTF7
```

But if I switch to ruby 2.0, then the list contains "UTF8".

So the problem turns to how to install "UTF8" for Ruby 1.9.1?

Comment: What's the ruby version you are using?

Comment: How `ASCII//IGNORE` is different from `ASCII` ? Do have any idea?

Comment: If you just want to convert to `UTF-8`, As an alternative you can also use `String#encode`. `str.encode('ASCII', 'UTF-8').gsub("\x00", "")`

Comment: The code is not mine, so I don't want to change the code. I hope to change my environment to fit the code.